# Python Splitting Strings Inside A File Via Space

Tags: python, list, binary

I'm trying out a binary search.I want it to split the values in:

> 751 755 762 763 774 777 785 797 798 809 814 817 822 824 827 841 847
>   866 881 891 903 904 908 913 918 919 925 933 940 948 949 968 972 981
>   988 992 995 1010 1012 1016 1018 1024 1026 1040 1051 1070 1072 1075
>   1082 1087 1088 1090 1098 1099 1114 1126 1135 1141 1144 1152 1153 1156
>   1164 1174 1177 1179 1180 1186 1192 1202 1204 1207 1218 1224 1235 1249
>   1251 1253 1272 1289 1290 1301 1302 1315 1322 ......(15K more numbers)

So that I could search for it using this code:

```
def binarySearch(newdata,number):


    i = 0
    lower = 0
    upper = len(newdata)






    while lower < upper:   
        x = lower + (upper - lower) // 2
        val = newdata[x]
        if number == val:
            return x
        elif number > val:
            if lower == x:   
                break        
            lower = x
        elif number < val:
            upper = x
    return None
```

If the binary isn't sorted I sort it using:

```
#SORT
def sorrt(data):
    result = []
    if len(data) < 2:
        return data
    mid = int(len(data)/2)
    y = sorrt(data[:mid])
    z = sorrt(data[mid:])
    while (len(y)>0) or (len(z)>0):
        if (len(y)>0) and (len(z)>0):
            if y[0] > z[0]:
                result.append(z[0])
                z.pop(0)
            else:
                result.append(y[0])
                y.pop(0)
        elif len(z)>0:
            for i in z:
                result.append(i)
                z.pop(0)
        else:
            for i in y:
                result.append(i)
                y.pop(0)

    return result
```

So my whole code is:

```
#BINARY SEARCH
fileName = 'sorted15000.txt'






#SORT
def sorrt(data):
    result = []
    if len(data) < 2:
        return data
    mid = int(len(data)/2)
    y = sorrt(data[:mid])
    z = sorrt(data[mid:])
    while (len(y)>0) or (len(z)>0):
        if (len(y)>0) and (len(z)>0):
            if y[0] > z[0]:
                result.append(z[0])
                z.pop(0)
            else:
                result.append(y[0])
                y.pop(0)
        elif len(z)>0:
            for i in z:
                result.append(i)
                z.pop(0)
        else:
            for i in y:
                result.append(i)
                y.pop(0)

    return result



def binarySearch(newdata,number):


    i = 0
    lower = 0
    upper = len(newdata)





#ACTIVATE
    while lower < upper:   
        x = lower + (upper - lower) // 2
        val = newdata[x]
        if number == val:
            return x
        elif number > val:
            if lower == x:   
                break        
            lower = x
        elif number < val:
            upper = x
    return None


start =0
with open(fileName) as file:  
    data = file.read().split()
start_time = time.clock()


    number = raw_input("What  number?: ")
    start_time  

    newdata = sorrt(data)


    pos = binarySearch(newdata,number)
    print pos
    print "\nTime: "
    print time.clock() - start_time, "seconds"
```

I want to pinpoint the location of the binary code im searching for in the variable `number`. But what I'm getting is a location so far away, for example 755 returns 7565. Something like that. Any ideas what caused the problem? I'm sure I correctly implemented `.split()` here

Comment: Tip: take a look at `bisect`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithms are correct, but they are operating on strings, and you want ints. With strings, you end up with `'123' < '5'`. So fix your input:

```
...
data = [int(x) for x in data]
number = int(number)
newdata = sorrt(data)
...
```